# Creating a Line in Gamemode between objects with the same tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm looking for help drawing a line from gameobjects to other gameobjects who have the tag "object"

edit1: The two objects as seen in the link are created and should have the same tag that I assigned the prefab. What I wanted to do was draw a line in game between each gameobject that had the same tag. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsmUG.jpg

Comment: this is a zilloin-times duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

If you need it for debug purposes you can use [Debug.DrawLine](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawLine.html) or [Gizmos.DrawLine](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.DrawLine.html).

If you need it as a feature in your gameplay you need to choose between [LineRenderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html) or  [GL.Begin(GL.LINES)](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.html), but last one is a pro feature.

Comment: thanks! Im relatively new too unity is it possible you could right a line of code showing how it works?

Comment: It depends on what do you need to do. Can you take a picture and edit or explain better your scenery?

Comment: sure, im making a quick gif to explain better one moment

Comment: unfortunately my proxy blocked your image, probably imgur is into my proxy rules =/

Comment: yeah that happens if your on a school network, to bypass it use chrome and get the extension called "dotvpn" with that enabled it allows you to access any blocked site

Comment: hehe, using tunnels at work is more complicated then at school ;)

Comment: really? Man I thought I was covered for the next few years but I guess not. Well if you get the chance in the next day or two I'd appriciate your help. And thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vectrosity. follow this link for guide. http://www.starscenesoftware.com/vectrosity.html